# Реализация элемента UI дизайна в Android

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, как реализовать такой элемент дизайна в Android? (интересует именно белая фигура).

Я сначала думала, просто сделать `ImageView` и сверху него отображать текст, но дело в том, что текст будет приходить с сервера и он может быть разной длины, следовательно нужно, что бы фигура расширялась либо становилась меньше в зависимости от длины текста. Можно ли нарисовать эту фигуру с помощью `onDraw()`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Может я не совсем понял вопрос, но это же очень просто.

**drawable/round_rectangle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="#90CAF9"/>
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
```

Далее:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_rectangle">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

В результате получаете:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD.**
Программно:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
relativeLayout.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
relativeLayout.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.round_rectangle));

setContentView(relativeLayout);

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
textView.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.");

relativeLayout.addView(textView);
```

Comment: О, похоже, а если мне нужно будет динамически создавать эти прямоугольники в Activity?

Comment: @Lucky_girl, Посмотрите **UPD** (но намного проще все это сделать в отдельном файле разметки).

Comment: А еще вопрос, вот, например, мне нужно будет на одном экране создать динамически несколько таких прямоугольников и что бы они были один под другим, как это правильно сделать? Создать цикл?

Comment: @Lucky_girl, Попробуйте использовать `RecyclerView` и, например, `CardView`. С помощью `RecyclerView` Вы сможете организовать некоторый список, элементами которого будут `CardView` – Ваши прямоугольники.

Comment: 's Это хорошая идея, спасибо!